# Custom android layout giving java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-statusbar

I am relatively new in android programming and I am facing some difficulties detecting the cause of the following error in my code:

> 10-18 18:15:45.083  31605-31605/? W/System.err? at com.app.name.widgets.SizeNotifierRelativeLayout.onLayout(SizeNotifierRelativeLayout.java:43)
>       10-18 18:15:45.092  31605-31605/? E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException

I am using a custom layout `com.app.name.widgets.SizeNotifierRelativeLayout` which is called by my xml file. The error occurs at the line 43 which contains the code `super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);` in the function below:

```
@Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        if (delegate != null) {
            View rootView = this.getRootView();
            int usableViewHeight = rootView.getHeight() - AndroidUtilities.statusBarHeight - AndroidUtilities.getViewInset(rootView);
            this.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
            int keyboardHeight = usableViewHeight - (rect.bottom - rect.top);
            delegate.onSizeChanged(keyboardHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

From my research, I have identifed that a **NullPointerException** error occurs as a result of having declared a variable without creating an object; but as I am new to java, it is a bit difficult for me to identify where the error occurs. Kindly point me in the right direction and I will really appreciate. Below are my activity, layout and SizeNotifierRelativeLayout files together with the logcat. Thanks in advance.

**Activity.java**

```
    package com.app.name;

import com.app.name.widgets.SizeNotifierRelativeLayout;

public class Activity extends ActionBarActivity implements ISideNavigationCallback, SizeNotifierRelativeLayout.SizeNotifierRelativeLayoutDelegate, NotificationCenter.NotificationCenterDelegate {

    private SizeNotifierRelativeLayout sizeNotifierRelativeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

        AndroidUtilities.statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight();

        sizeNotifierRelativeLayout = (SizeNotifierRelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chat_layout);
        sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.delegate = this;

        NotificationCenter.getInstance().addObserver(this, NotificationCenter.emojiDidLoaded);
    }

    /**
     * Get the system status bar height
     * @return
     */
    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**activity_view.xml**

```
    <com.app.name.widgets.SizeNotifierRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="com.app.name.Activity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chat_list_view"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:divider="@drawable/chat_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_msg_panel_smiles" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/emojiButton" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chat_edit_text1" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/chat_edit_text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/enter_chat1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/emojiButton"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/emojiButton"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/enter_chat1"
                android:hint="@string/type_your_message"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"

                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp" />

            <ImageView android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:id="@+id/enter_chat1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/chat_edit_text1"
                android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                android:paddingStart="13dp"
                android:paddingRight="17dp"
                android:paddingEnd="17dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_send" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.app.name.widgets.SizeNotifierRelativeLayout>
```

**SizeNotifierRelativeLayout.java**

```
    package com.app.name.widgets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.app.name.AndroidUtilities;

public class SizeNotifierRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private Rect rect = new Rect();
    public SizeNotifierRelativeLayoutDelegate delegate;

    public abstract interface SizeNotifierRelativeLayoutDelegate {
        public abstract void onSizeChanged(int keyboardHeight);
    }

    public SizeNotifierRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SizeNotifierRelativeLayout(Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SizeNotifierRelativeLayout(Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the soft keyboard height and report back to listener
     * @param changed
     * @param l
     * @param t
     * @param r
     * @param b
     */
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        if (delegate != null) {
            View rootView = this.getRootView();
            int usableViewHeight = rootView.getHeight() - AndroidUtilities.statusBarHeight - AndroidUtilities.getViewInset(rootView);
            this.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
            int keyboardHeight = usableViewHeight - (rect.bottom - rect.top);
            delegate.onSizeChanged(keyboardHeight);
        }
    }


}
```

**logcat**

> 10-18 18:51:12.154      712-712/? W/System.err? at com.app.name.widgets.SizeNotifierRelativeLayout.onLayout(SizeNotifierRelativeLayout.java:43)
>       10-18 18:51:12.164      712-712/? E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           java.lang.NullPointerException
>                   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2247)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1849)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1664)
>                   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2050)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
>                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
>                   at com.app.name.widgets.SizeNotifierRelativeLayout.onLayout(SizeNotifierRelativeLayout.java:43)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
>                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
>                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
>                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
>                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
>                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
>                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
>                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
>                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
>                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
>                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2230)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1994)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1181)
>                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4942)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
>                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
>                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       10-18 18:51:12.169     549-1386/? W/ActivityManager? Force finishing activity com.app.name/.Activity

Comment: The easiest way to find out, is to use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the line where the error occurs and find out which variable used on that line has the value `null`. See http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html for more information.